Is this circuit safe to put in my ceiling? What improvements could I make?

I uploaded a picture, is there a better way for me to share the circuit?
The addressable LEDs use up to 100 mA at 5 V, that is why I am using three 5 V power supplies in parallel, each offering 600 mA. The 4th power supply is used to power an 18650 cell.  If AC goes out, battery power kicks in using a buck converter to boost to 5 V.

Are the L1 thru L10 RGB LEDs going to be located a distance away from the U6-U8 power supplies and associated D1/D2?  If yes, then the +5v power wire feeding them them should also be fused in case of wiring fault.

To charge U11+B1.1 battery, suggest use a Li-Ion single cell charger IC or AC-DC wall charger (current limited with 4.2V max output), rather than the U9 constant voltage 5V supply.  Consider using Schottky diode for D1 and D2 to minimum voltage drop and heat generated.  Note the U6-U8 output voltage will need to be a diode drop (D1) higher than +5V.  A alternative method for backup power could be to connect an external battery-powered USB charger brick (+5V out) connected where KF305 header is, and then simply omit all the battery and support circuits (U9 and SX1308 and battery).

Finally, for the LED1 thru LED5, rather than connect these LEDs in parallel, instead place current limiting resistor in series with each LED and remove the shared bulk R2 current limit resistor.  As drawn now, each LED will have slightly different V_forward drop and frequently one or two will be brighter than the rest.  The individual series R will make them much closer to same brightness.

You could make life much easier for the people helping you if the shematic doesn't look like a bowl of spaghetti: https://resources.altium.com/p/creating-elegant-and-readable-schematics

safe is relative, but you should only put devices approved to go in a ceiling into the ceiling, otherwise, if there is a fire, perhaps even one you didn't cause, you will be liable for any damages and your insurance won't cover it.

Using parallel power supplies seems... dodgy. Why not just use a single PSU rated for sufficient current?

Seems last time I remember searching for ac to dc converters there weren't many options available, and the ones offered looked pretty big with exposed coils/wiring.  Will take time to see if I find better power supply
@dandavis  I forgot to mention that I plan to install in Mexico.  Here houses are build out of centerblocks and cement, so worst case scenario I would fry the wires, but the house wouldn't catch on fire.

Definitely not safe by any metric.
There is no fuse or other manufacturer suggested mains voltage protection circuits befoe the mains supplies.
The outputs of the supplies are shorted together without any indication they can be paralleled for higher output current, and if any supply burns out, the remaining supplies become overloaded.
Also one supply is connected directly paralleled with a lithium battery through a BMS. But there is no charging circuit for lithium batteries. The BMS is not a charger and does not handle charging, it is only a BMS. Or if it does charging, then it is a charger, not just a BMS.

As you can tell I know little to nothing about electronics.  I was under impression that the power supply modules had protection circuits included.  Would you suggest I add a 3A fuse on the mains voltage input?
Will also take time to read more about BMS vs battery charging.  I thought they were the same thing.
I do have a device at the moment with the 5v power supply attached to the 1S BMS with a battery.  It charges VERY slow, took over 24 hours to charge, but it did charge.  I do understand that because it "worked" it doesn't mean I am doing it right

So looked up info for the BMS I am using, it says:
"1S 3.7V 3A
Features:

high-accuracy voltage detection circuit;
terminal of the charger using high voltage device;
Built-in three-stage over-current detection circuit (over-current 1, over-current 2, load short circuit);
MOS transistor can control the battery charge and discharge;
Parameter:
Over charge voltage: 4.25±0.05V
Over charge release voltage:4.23±0.05V
Over discharge voltage:2.54±0.1V
Max continuous charging current: 2A
Max continuous Discharging current: 2A
Over current protection: 3A

Size: L40W4T3mm"

@CancunManny Nice specs but it stll is a BMS like you see from the specs and you have simply connected a battery through BMS to a voltage supply and have no charger.

I am under the impression that the BMS does both, "4) MOS transistor can control the battery charge and discharge"  When I look up battery charger I only seem to find stand alone chargers used for 18650s or rechargeable AA and AAA batteries.

I am looking at TP4056 which is "Lithium battery charging board 1A overshoot and overdischarge protection".  But how could I use that TP4056 with a BMS.
It would really help me out if you could tell me which component I should use with the BMS or which component I should substitute the BMS with

@CancunManny A BMS is not a charger and cannot be used as one. Where are you looking? Do your searches on proper electronics distributors like Mouser, Digikey, or Newark.

I keep looking for diagrams of the correct way to handle battery packs, and all I find use BMS with a regular v input (by regular I mean 5v, 9v, 12v).  I haven't found a diagram that shows BMS with a separate charging circuit.
I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQyYtNHc5o0   The video shows battery "charges" when input volts are over 4.2V but less than 5.9V
He also shows how he connects load to p- and p+ and at 2.4V it shuts off.  Yet found old post from so called expert that claims loads go on b- and p+, and charge input at p- and p+

@CancunManny You don't believe how many people get it wrong and teach other people to do it wrong and then hear it the first time when asking here. Building DIY lithium battery circuits is not for beginners and not suitable for first project. Yes, the wording you paste is correct, a battery is charged through the BMS but the charging is performed by a charging circuit. I mean, you don't simply put a 12V supply to a 12V car battery or 12V NiMH pack either, you use a charger that charges at correct rate and tops up the battery and stops charging when full. BMS just balances and protects.

Finding a 600mA (or more) 5V supply with battery backup that can be safely and legally placed elsewhere in the ceiling or walls should be easy from generally trusted suppliers like Eaton or GE.  Then the custom circuit becomes just a small 5V gadget that can sit in a translucent plastic box that looks like a lamp while nicely diffusing the pinpoint LEDs .
Because 600mA will have a measurable drop through thin wires and the needed fuse, the wires from power supply to 5V gadget need to be fairly thick to keep the wire resistance in each direction under 0.5Ω (1Ω total, 0.6V drop, use less Ω for less drop) .  Also remember that $$600mA \times 5V DC$$ is 3W of heat that needs to safely escape the box to avoid overheating and fire, while $$(600mA)^2 \times 1 \Omega$$ is 0.36 W of heat that needs to escape the wires.
For example 30ft of AWG19 copper should stay under 0.5Ω in each direction with a 0.02Ω to spare for the fuse and errors (using US units for your convenience) .

Thank you for such good info.  The little I know I've learned watching youtube videos.  I do know just because I saw a video doesn't mean they are doing it right.
I've ran similar setup without diodes and transistors and all worked as expected.  Also know just because "it works" doesn't mean it works good and/or safe.
I am aware of the voltage drop, specifically with diodes. Most of the modules I am connecting work with 4v or more.
I plan to fit the whole circuit in a circular PCB board of less than 25cm in diameter
